# Is this considered a cyclic dependency (is this good practice)?

Tags: java, oop

Hi I am a new Java programmer and have a small question about class design.

I understand that something like this is a cyclic dependency and is probably not a way to structure a project:

```java
public class Course {
    private ArrayList<Student> students;

    public Course (ArrayList<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
}


public class Student {
    private Course course;

    public Student (Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

But what if Student.java is changed to:

```java
public class Student {
    private int courseId;

    public Student (int courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }
}
```

so that `courseId` can be used to retrieve the course from a DAO or something. Is this still a good structure? Since now each Course still *cares about* Students. and each Student still *cares about* Courses.

Comment: First and foremost, try to finetune your question so that it doesn't appear like one that requires an opinionated answer. About your question, the new approach is not cyclic and is hence preferable. `courseId` provides an alternative way to reference the Student class.

Comment: This isn't about cyclical dependency. This is relationship modeling

Comment: Your Student class has a disconnect. You assume that a Student has only one course. I would change that to an ArrayList<Course>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reciprocal references are fine, all database entities exist side-by-side referring to each other.

The constructors must allow the creation, not being barred that they only can be created if the other already exists.

Hence maybe two constructors.

```
public class Course {
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public Course() {
    }

    public Course (List<Student> students) {
        this.students.addAll(students);
    }
}


public class Student {
    private Course course;

    public Student (Course course) {
        this.course = course;
        course.addStudent(this);
    }
}
```

With databases one often has numeric IDs, but many Object/Relational mappings can still allow you the classes above, under the hood using the IDs (JPA, eclipseLink, hibernate). It is not needed to have assymetrically IDs and object references.

You should not use concrete implementations (ArrayList) but be most flexible (List).

Also it might be better not to expose the field's internal data (`students`) for changing outside.

---

***About generalisations (`List`) and implementations (`ArrayList`)***

Some (scripting) languages have just one type for a collection. Java was
designed to provide several implementations for one interface.

So you can decide whether to implement a data structure for Map as fast HashMap or ordered TreeMap. In general the users only need to now about Map. You need not overspecify your code, and can even redesign simply using a different implementation class.

```
List<String> list = ...
Collections.sort(list);
list.add(...);

List<String> convert(List<String> list) { ... }
```

In the code above your `convert` can deal with *any* kind of List; you have written a more generic algorithm not just for an ArrayList. And in the method you can either return an ArrayList or a LinkedList. This makes code changes due to the wrong overspecification unlikely.

[Coding Against Interfaces](https://medium.com/better-programming/code-against-interfaces-not-implementations-37b30e7ab992) of Nick Hodges (pardon the wrong electric outlets and TypeScript).

Comment: Since I've decided to make all my classes immutable, I'm afraid that if I change some part of Course (e.g. the name), that the Course in Student might not get updated, would it still be ok for Student to just store the id and let CourseDAO to fetch the updated Course from database?

Comment: One often sees that only a builder factory may create the entity object that then is returned as immutable object. Alternatively one can hold the relations separately. You evidently tend to IDs, which is certainly more verbose coding, but I do not see any drawback otherwise. I would accept such a design. Immutable entities sounds interesting - not what one would expect from a database. But really interesting.

Comment: I have another question: If I can look up the students who are taking a course using StudentDAO e.g. getStudentsInCourse("Biology"), then does Course need to contain a list of Students? Or can I just look up from database each time

Comment: There should be no redundant holding of data (exception caching). Better leave those things to the database and worry about database indexes needed. Really I would give JPA, say in the form of eclipseLink, a small research. Because with immutable objects probably newer/older instances come to play too.

Comment: currently im using json/tsv in txt files :p. But I have seperated the DAO from the objects so hoepfully I can implement some JPA/SQL stuff in the future, thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 5):

The first snippet can be considered a valid design (with a small modification, see below). Suppose you have an academy:

- To enroll a `Student`, the student needs to pick a course, hence the constructor `public Student (Course course)`
- And a `Course` has a list of enrolled students, BUT, it is created with no students at first. They are added later on.

In fact I could use it like this:

```
public class Course {
    private String name;
    private List<Student> students;

    public Course (String name) {
        this.name = name;
        students = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
    }
}


public class Student {
    private Course course;

    public Student (Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
}

/// -- now...

Course history = new Course("History");
Student historyStudent = new Student(history);
history.add(historyStudent);
```

---

As a side note, there may be multiple variations of this design, but my point is, your design is almost valid, except for the small modification of not setting the list of students on course initialization.

Answer (score 5):

You'd honestly be better served doing this in a DAO / POJO way, and decoupling your Courses and your Students

If you were using a SQL database, you'd probably set up tables like

```
Course
Student
Enrollment
```

Where Enrollment has a Course, a Student, and a start and maybe an end date. This way, Course and Student are decoupled.

I recommend you model your classes like this

Comment: Agreed. Logic wise this seems like a scenario that would better suite a many-to-many relationship instead of a many-to-one relationship like the current setup support. Typically, there are many Students associated to a single Course and many Courses associated to a single Student.

Answer (score 4):

In models, especially backed by a database - this type of cyclic dependency is not considered bad. In fact, it's very common with ORMs (probably in 95% of all Java projects you would see something like that).

The option with courseId is - on the other hand - is a worse idea: it leaks a technical aspect of the model (if it's meant to reflect some surrogate primary key) into the Java domain.

Standard disclaimer: calling software architecture "good" or "bad" on a basis of a couple of snippets is like judging a building architecture based on a brick.

Comment: With the caveat of at least one default empty constructor presumably.